# Android app behaves differently between developer's device and tester's device

Tags: android

I've got an Android app which works perfectly on all the devices I've tested on, by installing via Android Studio or downloading to the app from Crashlytics (Twitter's beta distribution product among other things).

Unfortunately when the client installs the app (via Crashlytics) it doesn't work correctly for them (relating to bluetooth connection functionality).

Does anyone know of any differences that could result from this situation? Are the devices I've tested on somehow setup differently to the tester's device because mine have been used in a dev environment..?

Comment: How many clients have installed the app? All your clients have the same problem or only one? If there were problems with a single client then I think that is a problem with the phone of your client. If they were with many clients then it could be something related to the version of your app that you uploaded in Crashlytics

Comment: Hi @JorgeCasariego, it's two clients who have installed it and both seem to be having the same issue. I've tried it from Crashlytics myself too and it's been fine, albeit on a device that had previously been used for development. So I can only assume that installing an app on a device from Eclipse/Studio somehow makes my bluetooth functionality magically work...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well got both the clients devices in and they worked first time for me so I'm not sure what was going on, they seemed to be doing everything right but I've got nothing more to go on at this point!